# Access Synology NAS through domain name

Tags: networking, dns, nas, synology, domain-name

I'm want to access my Synology NAS with domain name.

So I made a new DDNS inside my NAS control panel `test.synology.me` then I can access my NAS through the Internet with `test.synology.me:63924` (I don't know where the port come from) but without this port this DDNS don't work.

Then I added a new `SRV` records inside my domain name control panel.

```
nas IN SRV 10 40 63924 test.synology.me.
```

I waited 72h for the DNS propagation but I still getting an error when I'm trying accessing my NAS through the new subdomain pointing on this records.

> This site can’t be reached
>
> nas.okok.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

I tried with the `test.quickconnect.to` given by synology but I get the same error.

I have maybe created the wrong records ? Did I miss something ?

Do you have some clues ?

Comment: What does your setup look like? How did you try to access the site? The error would suggest it's resolved to an invalid domain.

Comment: I access the NAS with `test.synology.me:63924` and I access the site with `nas.okok.com` who should redirect to my NAS

Comment: But you didn't define the actual name `nas.okok.com` but instead just a `srv` record? You could look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015138/how-to-redirect-dns-to-different-ports) as it looks like what you're trying to do. So you would end up (probably) with something like `_nas._tcp.okok.com` as the name. But you would need to have some application that actually handles the SRV record if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: "I don't know where the port come from" - It is the default port Synology uses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give details of your domain name control panel, so I can't be specific with instructions.

But I wouldn't expect the port to feature in your domain name record, what you need is a CNAME record mapping `nas.okok.com` to `test.synology.me`.

With that correct and propagated, you'd access it with `nas.okok.com:63924`.

If you don't like that you'll need to do a port forwarding on the internet modem/router that your nas is sitting behind and map external port 80 to port 63924 at your nas ip address.